# Is USB host always protected from reverse current?

Tags: usb

Does the USB specifications require that USB ports of a USB Host device are always protected from reverse current? If one connects a USB host to a different USB host for some reason, is it natural that one breaks? For example, one can connect two PCs using a USB cable. If this is really a serious problem, then I think USB would not be as popular as how it is now.

Comment: No, they aren't "protected". Indeed, many portable devices are specifically designed to be charged via that same port. Why do you think that this is a "serious problem"?

Comment: I thought that behind the USB port there is a voltage source, and the source is not meant to sink current.

Comment: Also PC is not supposed to be charged via USB2.0 port. This question was about USB hosts.

Comment: In the era when classic USB was designed there was no legitimate role for host-host (ie A-A) cables so this would not be a configuration users were expected to achieve.  They first turned up in dollar stores, which says a lot.  What may exist to handle transients and faults in *expected* configurations is a different story.

Comment: In principle could one assume that all desktops and laptops are not damaged by a reverse current? I didn't find an answer from technical documents yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In principle could one assume that all desktops and laptops are not
>   damaged by a reverse current?

No, you cannot assume this, especially in such a generic form. Some (high-end) desktops might have high-side switches to control VBUS and limit output current, but most do not have this electronics, and use fuses. Fuses do not protect from reverse currents. Some hi-side switches do have reverse current protection, some don't.

Again, the result may depend on the level of applied voltage. If you apply a 5-V (+-5%) source to a VBUS on a standard USB port, it is likely that the voltage difference will be "absorbed" over resistive elements (wires-traces-fuses), and just an overcurrent of some sort might occur, with no damage. But if you apply a 19-V 4.5-A power brick to VBUS on a standard Type-A port, I am sure some bad things will happen to your PC.

You won't find any "technical documents" on reverse currents because the entire USB design prevents "accidental" reverse flow on USB ports. In legacy USB (Type-A Type-B connectors) this protection was achieved by mandatory cables, which were only A to B, and not anything else. In advanced USB with symmetrical Type-C connectors it is achieved with a requirement of "no VBUS active ever" until sides determine their power roles over CC-interface.

Comment: These blanket statements simply aren't true, "which were only A to B" I have A to A cables they often come with portable hdd. Re "You won't find any "technical documents" " I'm sure I've seen some.

Comment: He's asking a yes or no question about the spec, a particular implementation may or may not follow the spec.
ps https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slva454/slva454.pdf?ts=1656269664808&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F

Comment: @JasonK. - The HDD's A-to-A cables are in violation of USB specifications, period. These devices/cables are a matter of deep past. You might have any kind of junk in your old box of cables, it does not change USB specifications. And your comments contradict each other. Please throw away all A-A cables unless they have orange-colored overmold - these are USB debug cables, and they don't have VBUS connection through.